# Why does post-slug not get saved for drafts?

Tags: slug, save-post

I am trying to get the value of the 'new-post-slug' (the bit that you can edit to customize your slug for a post, but bizarrely doesn't have a 'name' attribute as you'd expect a form field to have ... the update must be done in ajax in the background)

What I am stuck on is 2 things:

- Why do posts not get their post_name (slug) updated on saving a draft? (not autosaving, I mean hitting the 'Save Draft' button)
- If I was to try and do this manually (using the [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook), how can I get the value of the 'new-post-slug' (since this field is not available in the $_POST var). I guess I could try and do a pre-form-submit jQuery append-to-form type thing which gets this field .

When using the  `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` to catch the filename before it gets uploaded, the post_name (the slug) is not set:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'check_images_file_to_slug', 10, 2);

public function check_images_file_to_slug($image_info)
{  
    // Get the parent post ID, if there is one
    if( isset($_GET['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    } elseif( isset($_POST['post_id']) ) {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    }

    // Only do this if we got the post ID--otherwise they're probably in
    //  the media section rather than uploading an image from a post.
    if(is_numeric($post_id)) {
        /* @var @post WP_Post */
        $post = get_post($post_id);

        // Here $post->post_name (the slug), is empty for post-new.php (Adding new post)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar issue. I had to remove `remove_meta_box('slugdiv', ['post', 'page'], 'normal');` from my code. When you remove the *slugdiv* meta box the slug edit box for WP does stops working.

Answer (score -1):

When a new post is created (regardless of status) `post_name` which is the slug is saved to the WP_Post object.

You can fire off a [`wp_ajax_$youraction()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) in the backend to get the post object and return the slug.

Comment: Wrong.  post_name is not saved for drafts.